# flutter:i am getting this exception :Closure call with mismatched arguments:

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am trying to build my first app and it is working but when I open the filter screen in the drawer the screen turns red on the emulator and I am getting this exception and didn't know how to fix it ,there is the exception and then I wrote the filter screen code in the post:

Tried calling: _FiltersScreenState.build.()
Found: _FiltersScreenState.build.(dynamic) => Null

````
class FiltersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 static const routeName = '/filters';

 final Function saveFilters;
 final Map<String, bool> currentFilters;

 FiltersScreen(this.currentFilters, this.saveFilters);

 @override
 _FiltersScreenState createState() => _FiltersScreenState();
}

class _FiltersScreenState extends State<FiltersScreen> {
 bool _glutenFree = false;
 bool _vegetarian = false;
 bool _vegan = false;
 bool _lactoseFree = false;

 @override
 initState() {
   _glutenFree = widget.currentFilters['gluten'] as bool;
   _lactoseFree = widget.currentFilters['lactose'] as bool;
   _vegetarian = widget.currentFilters['vegetarian'] as bool;
   _vegan = widget.currentFilters['vegan'] as bool;
   super.initState();
 }

 Widget _buildSwitchListTile(
   String title,
   String description,
   bool currentValue,
   Function updateValue,
 ) {
   return SwitchListTile(
     title: Text(title),
     value: currentValue,
     subtitle: Text(
       description,
     ),
     onChanged: updateValue(),
   );
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('Your Filters'),
       actions: <Widget>[
         IconButton(
           icon: Icon(Icons.save),
           onPressed: () {
             final selectedFilters = {
               'gluten': _glutenFree,
               'lactose': _lactoseFree,
               'vegan': _vegan,
               'vegetarian': _vegetarian,
             };
             widget.saveFilters(selectedFilters);
           },
         )
       ],
     ),
     drawer: MainDrawer(),
     body: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
         Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
           child: Text(
             'Adjust your meal selection.',
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
           ),
         ),
         Expanded(
           child: ListView(
             children: <Widget>[
               _buildSwitchListTile(
                 'Gluten-free',
                 'Only include gluten-free meals.',
                 _glutenFree,
                 (newValue) {
                   
                   setState(
                     () {
                       _glutenFree = newValue;
                     },
                   );
                 },
               ),
               _buildSwitchListTile(
                 'Lactose-free',
                 'Only include lactose-free meals.',
                 _lactoseFree,
                 (newValue) {
                   
                   setState(
                     () {
                       _lactoseFree = newValue;
                     },
                   );
                 },
               ),
               _buildSwitchListTile(
                 'Vegetarian',
                 'Only include vegetarian meals.',
                 _vegetarian,
                 (newValue) {
                   
                   setState(
                     () {
                       _vegetarian = newValue;
                     },
                   );
                 },
               ),
               _buildSwitchListTile(
                 'Vegan',
                 'Only include vegan meals.',
                 _vegan,
                 (newValue) {
                   
                   setState(
                     () {
                       _vegan = newValue;
                     },
                   );
                 },
               )
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
} ```
````